# Error message: Invalid next control variable reference

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Trying to run the following loop but keep getting an invalid next control variable reference error. Cannot seem to work out the solution and I am sure it is a simple one.

The code works fine without the loop but when I have added the loop it has now failed.

```
Sub QC()

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim ws As String

For i = 1 To 2
For j = 0 To 1
ws = "Settings"

    Worksheets(ws).Range(Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 - j, 2)) = Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 - j, 3)
    Worksheets("QC").Cells(8, 5) = Worksheets("CE Results").Cells(9, 9)
    Worksheets(ws).Range(Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 - j, 2)) = Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5, 2)

    Worksheets(ws).Range(Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 - j, 2)) = Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 + j, 3)
    Worksheets("QC").Cells(10, 5) = Worksheets("CE Results").Cells(9, 9)
    Worksheets(ws).Range(Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5 - j, 2)) = Worksheets("QC").Cells(i * 5, 2)

Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: `Next j` not `Next k`

Comment: Have fixed that but doesn't seem to solve the error, still getting "invalid next control variable reference".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loop variables are `i` and `j`, in `Next` statement you have `k` and `i`., Swith `k` to `j`.

Also, order of `Next`s is wrong, becuase `Next i` corresponds to `For j`, so order of `Next`s should be:

```
Next j
Next i
```

Also, you can omit variables in `Next`, which would be les error prone.

One more note: use proper indentation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the `i` loop structure *first* you need to close it *last*. Always format your code correctly (use indentation as below) so you see that the loop structure you open last (here `j`) needs to be closed first.

You tried it the other way round so you got an error.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 0 To 1
        ' your code
    Next j
Next i
```

Also note that if you declare `Dim i, j As Integer` that means `j` is `Integer` but `i` is `Variant`. You must specify a type for **every** variable `Dim i As Long, j As Long` otherwise VBA assumes `Variant` by default.

And you should declare your variables as `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Actually you can always use `Long` instead of `Integer` as there is no benefit in using `Integer`: Also see [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520)

---

Additional recommendation:

Don't declare `Dim ws As String` instead

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")
```

and use it like:

```
ws.Range(…)
```

you can use this technique for your other worksheets too so your code gets a lot shorter and easier to maintain. Eg. if a name of a worksheet changes you have to change it only once in the `Set` statement.